# Convergence in probability, in the sense of weak convergence of measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I am reading a paper where the author has a family $(\rho_t : t \geq 0)$ of *random* probability measures (on the real line with Borel sigma-algebra), and a measure $\rho$. One of his theorems says that the measures $\rho_t$ converge to $\rho$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. He says 'they converge in probability, in the sense of weak convergence of measures.'

This combines two concepts in a way I don't quite understand. This is my interpretation - is this right?

Convergence in measure is metrizable, say by the measure $\mu$. Does the above mean that for all $\epsilon, \delta > 0$, there is a $T \geq 0$ such that for all $t \geq T$, we have

$$\mathbb{P} (\mu(\rho_t,\rho) > \delta) < \epsilon \quad ?$$

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures         or this one on math overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196504/weak-convergence-of-random-measures

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is right, except that I think you meant to say that $\mu$ induces the topology of weak convergence on the space of measures (not the topology of convergence in measure).